# Materialize collapse animation delay

Tags: html, css, materialize

How can I add animation delay in `collapse` using Materialize ?

**I tried this code**

```
$('.collapsible').collapsible({
    inDuration: 5000,
    outDuration: 5000
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you have a full working example? The code you are using is a jquery one but I do not see that selected as a tag.

Comment: I just copy the code here https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for you.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The Materialize Collapsible Example</title>
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">      
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
      <script type = "text/javascript"
         src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>           
      <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js">
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body class = "container"> 
      <h4>Simple Accordion</h4>
      <ul class = "collapsible" data-collapsible = "accordion">
         <li>
            <div class = "collapsible-header">
               <i class = "material-icons">filter_drama</i>First Section</div>
            <div class = "collapsible-body"><p>This is first section.</p></div>
         </li>
         
         <li>
            <div class = "collapsible-header">
               <i class = "material-icons">place</i>Second Section</div>
            <div class = "collapsible-body"><p>This is second section.</p></div>
         </li>
         
         <li>
            <div class = "collapsible-header">
               <i class = "material-icons">whatshot</i>Third Section</div>
            <div class = "collapsible-body"><p>This is third section.</p></div>
         </li>
      </ul>
      
 
<script>$('.collapsible-header').collapsible({
    inDuration: 5000,
    outDuration: 5000
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```